# Chess.com's daily problem-Why doesn't 1...Nf8 win the Nh7?

Tags: analysis, tactics, puzzles

Shouldn't 1...Nf8 win here too? Why not?

```
[FEN "r2qk2r/pp1nnp1N/4p1pQ/3pP3/4b1PP/P1B5/1PP1B3/R3KR2 b Qq - 0 1"]

1...Nf8??
```

Comment: You could have just put the position in an engine and it would have told you. You don't have to ask the StackExchange about that.

Comment: It loses due to Nf6#.

Comment: @SubhanKhan Not everyone is that experienced, or has the tools that you may have, or know how to get them...or even that they exist.

Comment: What is the full problem?

Comment: @John If it is beyond my answer below, what do you mean, what is the full problem? I showed the entire solution below. It is the sub-variation starting with 1...Ng8!

Comment: The title should read "1...Nf8," or else the post should be able to specify that it's Black's move, because I was momentarily very confused as to why White should play 1.Nf8.

Answer (score 19):

Frankly, you overlooked a major detail...Nf6+ in reply is mate. It is important to notice your "opponent's" moves too.

```
 [FEN "r2qk2r/pp1nnp1N/4p1pQ/3pP3/4b1PP/P1B5/1PP1B3/R3KR2 b Qq - 0 1"]

 1... Nf8 $4 (1... Ng8! 2. Qg7 (2. Nf6+ Qxf6 $1) 2... Qxh4+ 3. Kd2 Qxh7) 2. Nf6#
```

Comment: Nf6 is not only mate, but also wins the rook on h8 due to the discovered attack ;-). Unlike in the line Ng8, black does not have the reply Qxf6 here...